# radio labels not lining up in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I found this cute little css tabs animation @ codepen. Its perfect for what I need (after adaptions). It works on all browsers but IE 10+.

http://codepen.io/Kseso/full/JDFto/

Tested on chrome, Mozilla, Opera, all fine but on IE 11 the navigation tabs all bunch up and become useless. I am hoping that someone here might be able to solve this IE issue.

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:600,200|Great+Vibes);
@import url(http://weloveiconfonts.com/api/?family=fontawesome);
*, *:after, *:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
* {margin:0;padding:0;border: 0 none;position: relative;}
[class*="fontawesome-"]:before {font-family: 'fontawesome', sans-serif;}

html {
  background: #33485E;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: dosis, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
}

section {
  background: #31A66C;
  width: 80vw;
  max-width: 40rem;
  min-width: 390px;
  height: 25rem;
  margin: 4rem auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
article {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 5rem;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 1rem 2rem 0;
  overflow: auto;
  transition: .7s;
  transform: scale(0);
  transform-origin: center right;
  transition-delay: .1s;
}
article:before {
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-weight: 100;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1rem;
  right: 1rem;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
}
h2 img {
  width: 120px;
  height: auto;
  background: #f9f9f9;
  border: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
h2 span {
  font-family: Great Vibes;
  font-weight: 400;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
footer ul {
  width: 100%;
  color: #037B49;
}
footer li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 100;  
}
p, dl, ol {
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}
ol li {margin: 0 0 .5rem 1rem;}
dt {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-indent: 1.5rem;
}
nav {
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
nav:after {
  content:'';
  width: 25%;
  height: 5rem;
  background: #BEE3D1;
  position: absolute;
  transition: .5s;
}
input {
  display: none;
}
label {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  color: #BEE3D1;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .5s;
  z-index: 2;
}
label:hover {color: #1E6743;}
label:before {
  display: block;
  font-size: 3rem;
  line-height: 5rem;
  z-index: 2;
}
#profile:checked ~ nav [for='profile'],
#settings:checked ~ nav [for='settings'],
#posts:checked ~ nav [for='posts'],
#books:checked ~ nav [for='books'] {
  color: #1E6743;
  font-weight: 600;
}
#settings:checked ~ nav [for='settings'] {}
#profile:checked ~ nav [for='profile'] {}

#profile:checked ~ nav:after {
  left: 0;
}
#settings:checked ~ nav:after {
  left:25%;
  border-top: 0 none;
}
#posts:checked ~ nav:after {
  left: 50%;
}
#books:checked ~ nav:after {
  left: 75%;
}

#profile:checked ~ .uno,
#settings:checked ~ .dos,
#posts:checked ~ .tres,
#books:checked ~ .cuatro {
  display: block;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition-delay: .5s; 
}
a {color: rgba(0,0,0,.4)}
a:hover {color: rgba(0,0,0,.2)}
```

HTML

```
<section>
<input type="radio" id="profile" value="1" name="tractor" checked='checked' />    
<input type="radio" id="settings" value="2" name="tractor" />      
<input type="radio" id="posts" value="3" name="tractor" />
<input type="radio" id="books" value="4" name="tractor" />

  <nav>   
  <label for="profile" class='fontawesome-camera-retro'></label>
  <label for="settings" class='fontawesome-film'></label>
  <label for="posts" class='fontawesome-calendar'></label>
  <label for="books" class='fontawesome-list-alt'></label>
  </nav>

  <article class='uno'>
    <h2>
      <img alt=''  src='https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-wy4VbKjl-28/UXVqrCC_cCI/AAAAAAAAGi0/JZZvb9IaLCc/s550-no/K-bg-2.jpg' />
      KsesoCss
      <span>Spanish Css blog</span></h2>
   <footer>
    <ul>
      <li class='fontawesome-link'></li>
      <li class='fontawesome-paper-clip'></li>
      <li class='fontawesome-sitemap'></li>
      <li class='fontawesome-wrench'></li>
      <li class='fontawesome-magic'></li>
    </ul>
   </footer>
  </article>

  <article class='dos fontawesome-wrench'>
    <p>Si hay algún fenómeno en la web que sea lo más parecido a las setas eso son los blogs, cursos y enseñanzas web. Todo lo relativo a la divulgación, de cualquier materia o parcela del conocimiento humano, angelical o mefistofélico, tiene su oferta, sus "maestros" y sus cocinillas visionarios.</p>
  </article>

  <article class='tres fontawesome-file-alt'>
    <ol>
      <li>Dimensionado de imágenes y objetos en CSS</li>
      <li>Evita pulsaciones no deseadas al hacer scroll</li>
      <li>¿Qué es CSS?</li>
      <li>CSS Style Attributes. La especificación</li>
      <li>Múltiples labels por cada input </li>
      <li>Sintaxis de Css y Glosario de términos</li>
    </ol>
  </article>

  <article class='cuatro fontawesome-copy'>
    <dl>
      <dt>Guía de Transiciones Css</dt>
      <dd>Todas y cada una de las propiedades css que componen el grupo de las transitions con demos.</dd>
      <dt>@Font-face y sus problemas</dt>
      <dd>Los problemas más comunes y sus soluciones, que suelen presentarse al utilizar la regla @font-face de Css para mostrar los textos en tipografías distintas a las safety fonts.</dd>
    </dl>
  </article>
</section>
<h2><a href='http://codepen.io/Kseso/pen/heysk'>see you ver.1</a></h2>
```

Comment: i just wonder why I keep losing points for this post, it seems valid to me, works in all browsers but IE .... can any one tell me ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by changing

```
label:before {
  display: block;
  font-size: 3rem;
  line-height: 5rem;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

to

```
label:before {
/*  display: block;*/
  font-size: 3rem;
  line-height: 3;
  height: 5em;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

10 points to me :)

Comment: modified to vertically align labels center===

label:before {
/*  display: block;*/
  font-size: 3rem;
  line-height: 1.6;
  height: 5em;
  z-index: 2;
}